# What does the IP "192.168.1.1/24" indicate?

Tags: ip, rsync, tcpip, subnet

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Server Fault Wiki: How does Subnetting Work?](https://serverfault.com/questions/49765/server-fault-wiki-how-does-subnetting-work)

I'm setting up rsync and I see this in the config file:

```
hosts allow = 127.0.0.1 192.168.1.1/24
```

Does this indicate that all hosts on the local (192.168.1.*) can use rsync? It's been awhile since my networking class; I just want to understand...

Comment: @warner @kyle @splattne This question is much more specific and concise then the link you provided. What if someone didn't know this was subnetting? Ridiculous that this was closed; stop with the itchy trigger fingers people. You're doing more harm than good.

Answer (score 7):

Indeed, that means the first 24 bits of the 192.168.1.1 address are required while the remaining eight can be anything. This is called CIDR.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. The notation is CIDR - have a look **[here](https://serverfault.com/questions/12854/cidr-for-dummies)** for some more discussion.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it means 127.0.0.1 and 192.168.1.* are allowed.