# A Way To Determine IP Range From CIDR?

Tags: ip, ip-address, cidr

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does Subnetting Work?](https://serverfault.com/questions/49765/how-does-subnetting-work)

Is there a formula or a calculator for determining an IP address from CIDR that I was given: 38.103.17.160/27?

I would like to know the entire range of IP addresses from what I was given, but I have no idea how to break it down.

I am far, far from being a networking person so please go easy on me!

Comment: I am most likely never going to become a networking admin or need the level of complexity that the possible duplicate answer, or even the http://serverfault.com/questions/12854/cidr-for-dummies answer provides. I sell domain names and am having to look into some things on my server.  I just want to verify what someone else is telling me... 

If someday I am required to learn this stuff for my job, then I will certainly reference those.

Comment: The basics of IP addresses and CIDR are just that - basics.  Very, very basics.  This was correctly closed.

Comment: If the explanations are too complex for you why not use one of the 10 gazillion subnet calculators on the Internet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. That little number is supposed to give you that very information, but does require a bit of calculating. Have a look at this article which explains subnetting and how to calculate how many hosts/subnets that /27 refers to:

[How does IPv4 Subnetting Work?](https://serverfault.com/questions/49765/how-does-subnetting-work)

And once you know how it works, you can use some calculators to make work easier :)

- http://www.subnetmask.info/
- ipcalc - a tool in *nix systems
- there are hundreds more with a simple Google search for 'subnet calculator'

EDIT: Jason mentioned my favourite one that I had forgotten about:
[A Way To Determine IP Range From CIDR?](https://serverfault.com/questions/315387/a-way-to-determine-ip-range-from-cidr/315391#315391)

Comment: It would be better to explain it within the answer itself

Answer (score 1):

http://www.subnet-calculator.com/ is awesome for those (like me) that don't like to do the math themselves.

Comment: Where do I plug in that "/27" on that calculator?  Would that be the "Mask Bits"?  If I do that then the range is 38.103.17.161 - 38.103.17.190 which doesnt include the IP 38.103.17.160  or is that range correct?

And I will take a look at the duplicate too - sorry folks.

Comment: That's correct. 38.103.17.160 is the network id, it's not a usable address.

Comment: Ah, yes. There it is. I hadn't used it for a while so I didn't remember the address for this tool. I prefer it out of all the online based calculators I've seen.

Answer (score 0):

I generally use a tool called sipcalc (http://www.routemeister.net/projects/sipcalc/) to get a quick answer on subnetting questions, though you can also go through and do the binary math to figure it out.